# Why do Carrierwave and asset pipeline appear to interpret config.asset_host differently?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, carrierwave

This issue occurs in a Prawn PDF generator in my Rails app, where I have the following line:

```
image open(@user.avatar.url)
```

In tests this line began failing with the following error:

```
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /images/fallback/default.png
```

Avatar is a Carrierwave uploader, with a default image ([see here](http://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#user-content-providing-a-default-url))

```
def default_url(*args)
  ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("images/fallback/default.png" )
end
```

This seemed like it would be an easy fix — define the asset host in test.rb

```
config.asset_host = Rails.root.join('app', 'assets').to_s
```

but then all my JS enabled feature tests began failing

```
Capybara::Poltergeist::JavascriptError:
One or more errors were raised in the Javascript code on the page.
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: SomeVariable
```

because the paths are being constructed with two `assets`, e.g.

`...app/assets/assets/jquery..`

I am clearly doing something "unconventional" that goes against the Rails way of doing things. So I'm wondering what the convention is here.

One solution would be to move where I'm defining the asset folder from test.rb to the uploader.

```
#config/environments/test.rb
config.asset_host = Rails.root.join('app').to_s
#app/uploaders/avatar.eb
def default_url(*args)
  ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("assets/images/fallback/default.png" )
end
```

but this would mean that `helpers.asset_path` is not in fact calling the asset path but the app folder, which again seems to go against Rails convention.

I had thought the localhost would work

```
config.asset_host = "http://localhost"
```

but again JS files are failing

I'm sure I'm overlooking something obvious here. Grateful for pointers in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this boils down to mixing up of various meanings of path and URL.

First off `asset_host`  is used when you want to serve your asset files from a different server to your application (ie from a cdn). If you look at the source to [`asset_path`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-asset_path) rails first computes the path to the asset and then prepends the host. This creates a URL that the browser will later try to fetch, so prepending a path like `/Users/andy/some_app` doesn't make sense

Setting it to `http://localhost` doesn't work because that assumes the default http port, whereas capybara runs your app on a random port. You shouldn't ever need to set `asset_host` in the test environment.

Moving on to carrierwave, `avatar.url`  also provides the URL (in your case just the path portion) from the point of view of the browser - it's designed to be embedded in an img tag for example. The `open` method on the other hand know nothing about browsers and servers and just wants a path to a file on the local filesystem.

If you want a local filesystem path then you need `avatar.path` method. As far as I know, there is no equivalent of `default_url` for path, so you need to be prepared for it to return nil (and replace it with the path to your fallback instead)

```
#config/environments/test.rb
# do not set config.asset_host

#pdf_generator.rb
image open(@user.avatar.path)

#app/uploaders/avatar.rb
def path(*args)
  if model.avatar?
    super
  else
    "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/fallback/" + ["default_",version_name, ".png"].compact.join('')
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks @frederick, that's a good explanation and clears up a lot of questions. But `avatar.path` essentially returns the same as `avatar.url` without the host, correct? In this case `/images/fallback/default.png`, which is what `avatar.url` is returning in my tests anyway, and is not suitable for the `open` method. Should `open` respond to `avatar.path`?

Comment: Compare the values and see what they return - shouldn't be the same thing. Also, the fallback image is a bit of a special case - i thing path will just return nil there.

Comment: Correct, with fallback it returns `nil`. If an image is set, `avatar.path` returns `avatars/filename.jpg` whereas `avatar.url` returns `http://path/to/app/avatars/filename.jpg`. So I would need a method that, `if avatar.path.nil?` returns `/app/assets/images/fallback/default.png`. Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: thanks, this got things working! I've edited your answer to add the code that worked. Suggestions for improvement welcome. Thanks for the help!